# Excel Check String is Valid with a Template

Tags: excel, templates

In Excel, I have this template for checking SMS format:

```
Your appointment is confirmed with [name] at [hh:mm] on [dd/mm/yy]. Please bring all your related documents.
```

The actual SMS will be the same except the tokens (delimited by brackets `[]`) will replaced with actual values.

How can I check a list of SMSs if any SMS doesn't follow the previous template? I have multiple template with a list of SMS sent in one month.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your input data in `A2`. You can use the following in `B2`:

```
=LET(texts, {"Your appointment is confirmed with "," at "," on ",
 ". Please bring all your related documents."}, 
 SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(texts,A2)))=4)
```

`LET` is just to organize better the expression. It returns `TRUE` if all the input strings match, otherwise it returns `FALSE`. The rest is just to extend the formula down.

Here is the output:

[image: Sample excel file]

**Notes:**

- Excel doesn't have RegEx function, except via VBA. Check this [link](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-regex-formulas/) for this approach.
- You can add additional checks for the token values introduced if you want, but based on your question, the above formula would be enough for your needs.